# In ruby, get content in brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

> Eclipse Developments (Scotland) Ltd t/a Martin & Co (Glasgow South)

I need to get the last (always the last, however sometimes the only) brackets value, so in this case "Glasgow South".

I know I should use `.sub` but can't work out the correct regex.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Usually `sub` is used for *sub*-stitutions. What you need is `scan`:

```
test = "Eclipse Developments (Scotland) Ltd t/a Martin & Co (Glasgow South)"

test.scan(/\(([^\)]+)\)/).last.first
# => "Glasgow South"
```

The reason for the odd `.last.first` call is `scan` returns an array of arrays by default. You want the first (and only) element of the last match.

Translating that regexp, which can be prickly for the uninitiated:

```
\(     # A literal bracket followed by...
(      # (Memorize this)
[^)]+  # One or more (+) characters not in the set of: closing-bracket [^)]
)      # (End of memorization point)
\)     # ...and a literal closing bracket.
```

Comment: Great, this works fine on 2 instances. I forgot to mention but sometimes, the string will only contain 1 set of parenthesis (which will need to be selected). Sorry!

Comment: If you look at the output of the `scan` method, which is something best done inside `irb`, you can pick out whatever bits you want. This just extracts things inside brackets, so `[0][0]` would be the contents of the first brackets, `[1][0]` for the second set, and so forth. Remember that `last` will pull the last set, which for a single set is the first as well.

Comment: Sorry, it was me being a muppet. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Regexps are greedy; if you ask for `.*` it will match as much as possible. For that reason, the following will work:

```
test = "Eclipse Developments (Scotland) Ltd t/a Martin & Co (Glasgow South)"
test =~ /.*\((.*)\)/
answer = $1
# => "Glasgow South"
```